# Backbone.js error in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, backbone.js

I'm just wondering why  `Backbone.view.extend()` in my wordpress plugin doesn't work at all.

Instead, I've found in Wordpress codex that they use `wp.Backbone.view` for all their features that uses Backbone view. Then, I tried to change mine with prefixes `wp` like that, and guess what, it works!

The question, why should I use the prefixes? Is that the requirement from wordpress or only me who misunderstand it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are using is a Wordpress plugin, extending the original Backbone View.
If this is the plugin you are using:

http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/nav.html?wp-includes/js/wp-backbone.js.source.html

Then you'll see that the code starts with:

```
// Create the WordPress Backbone namespace.
wp.Backbone = {};
```

The Backbone View:

```
// wp.Backbone.View
  // ----------------
  //
  // The base view class.
  wp.Backbone.View = Backbone.View.extend({});
```

Thus adding functionality on top of the original Backbone View.

Comment: Does the model works the same way? `wp.Backbone.Model`?

Comment: I'm not sure what library you're using, but you should be able to find this in either the documentation, or by scanning the source code.